# Remove the top part of Android apps

Tags: android

I just started Android programming and I have a very simple question. It's also how can I remove the part specified in the image below?
[image]

Comment: **`getSupportActionBar().hide();`**

Comment: this top part of Android apps is called ActionBar search themes for no actionbar

Answer (score 0):

try using this code inside on your `OnCreate`

do it like this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //other codes ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to styles.xml and Change this DarkActionBar to NoActionBar

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```